# After post form is submitted and username is checked for duplicate, how to send this info to javascript on form page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make my registration form show a message, on the same page as the registration form, that a username is taken if it is taken after the form is submitted.

I made a registration form that posts input to the file add-user.php. inside my add-user.php file I have two functions. ->nameTaken functions checks if a username is already in the database, and ->insert inserts names into a database if they are not taken.

here is the add-user.php file code :

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/javascript');

$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if(!$app['database']->nameTaken($_POST['username'])){

    $app['database']->insert('users', [

        'name' => $_POST['username'],

        'password' => $hash

    ]);
};
```

here is the nameTaken function that is in another file :

```
 public function nameTaken($username){

        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE name = :name');

        $statement->execute(array('name' => $username));

        $res = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $exists = array_pop($res);

        if ($exists > 0) {

            $json = array(
                'success' => false
            );

            echo json_encode($json);

            return true;

        } else {
            //the name can be made
            $json = array(
                'success' => true
            );

            echo json_encode($json);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is working properly, but I don't know how to send this information to my html when I'm redirected back to the file with my form, so that it can show a message if a registration was succesful or if it failed because the username is aready taken.

I tried making a json output for this and getting it with a promise, but immediately after the form was submitted I'm redirected to my form page and the ajax call is null. I've only seen questions for how to do this while the username/password is being typed into the registration form on here, but I want to show the message after the registration form is submitted. How would I do this?

my promise ajax request to the php post file :

```
window.onload = function(){

    function get(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
          xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
          xhr.send();
        });
      }

    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', () => {
            let promise = get('/controllers/contact.php').then((name) => {
            console.log(name);
        });
    });
}
```

I can't use this javascript because it executes before the php file is loaded, and then after the php file loads and I'm redirected to the page with my form, everything in the php file is erased, and my promise ajax request has already been executed.

my html :

```
<form method='POST' action='/users' id='register'>

            Username<input type='text' name='username' required>

            Password<input type='password' name='password' required>

            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>

        </form>
```

These are the errors I'm getting in my server

```
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:07 2018] 127.0.0.1:36690 [200]: /
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:07 2018] 127.0.0.1:36694 [200]: /registerFail.js
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:10 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 5
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: app in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36734 [500]: /controllers/add-user.php - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36738 [302]: /users
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36744 [200]: /
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36750 [200]: /registerFail.js
```

First I'm on the main '/' page. Immediately when I submit my form, the ajax request runs before the php file is loaded and so everything is undefined, then when my php file loads and checks for the username, everything works fine and the username is either reject or put into my database. Then I'm redirected back to the the '/' directory with my form. I can't show an error message because the ajax executes before the php file is loading and I don't know how to fix this. I want to show the error message when I'm redirected back to the form page after the file has loaded. What would the code look like for me to do this?

```
<?php

$router->get('', 'controllers/index.php');

$router->get('about', 'controllers/about.php');

$router->get('contact', 'controllers/contact.php');

$router->post('users', 'controllers/add-user.php');

$router->post('login', 'controllers/login.php');
```

This is my router. controllers/add-user.php does not exist unless I make a post request to it. The other places, I can just type in a url and go to them.

Comment: Please post your HTML and JavaScript

Comment: If you post the form, you wouldn't use AJAX and visa-versa. As your code is written, you would have an ```else``` clause that re-directs to the original page, passing a message or status so it would display the error (user ID already in use)

Comment: _Note:_ `header('Content-type: text/javascript');` should be `header('Content-type: application/json');`. You're returning json, not javascript.

Comment: You should also not have that `echo json_encode()` in your `nameTaken()`-method. Just return true or false (like you're doing) and let the caller handle the response. As it's currently written, you can't return the status of the insert, since you've already echoed a complete json-object.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thats what I'm trying to do but how can I pass the information from my php file to the html? I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How can I connect the ajax caller to my response though? The ajax executes before the php file is loaded, and the php file loads and then deletes itself after it is made since it's a post request.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean. Ajax is simply a asynchronous http request to the PHP file. The PHP file does it's job and echoes a json-response which is what is returned. Don't know what you mean by _"the php file loads and then deletes itself after it is made since it's a post request"_? Nothing get's "deleted". Here's a good guide about Ajax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: There is an event.preventDefault() missing in your submit event handler

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The ajax request makes a request to the php file immediately after the form is submitted, which is before when the php file loads. Because of that I've been getting errors in my server code and a 500 error on the ajax request. Then when the php file does load, it echos the correct json and either makes a new user or doesn't, then I'm redirected back to a different file, and the ajax request already executed so I can't connect to the php file to see if I get errors or not. I'll update my answer with the server errors I've been getting.

Comment: We might be talking about different things, but an ajax request is what loads the PHP file. It's simply a separate HTTP request (just like if you would access it through the browser) so I don't know what you mean by _"which is before when the php file loads"_. You don't "load" any PHP file before you make a http request to it (since it's the request that tells the web server to load the file in the first place).

Comment: MY promise get request then. I made the promise request to get the json object saying either success or false to whether the username is taken inside of the post php file. I can not get that json object though because the promise request is made before the php file is loaded and has made any json objects. I've been able to get json objects with my promise request from other php files, but they were get files. This php file is only made after the form is submitted, and then it can't be accessed.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a get or a post request. The request cycles are the same. The only difference is how the Ajax request is sending the data _to_ the PHP file. The response doesn't differ. I would recommend that you read the URL I posted earlier properly. They might be able to explain it better than I am.

Comment: I can not access my the add-user.php file inside my browser. if I type the url link to it in my browser, nothing appears because it is only made after the registration form is submitted. After the add-user.php file loads and checks the username, I am redirected to '/' and I can not access it anymore because it is only made when the form is submitted. I know how to use ajax, my problem is I don't know how to structure my code so I can get the message from my add-user.php file to see if a username is taken or not or if I'm  using the right methods to do this. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: From the log: _"/controllers/add-user.php - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php"_ - That's most likely why you think you can't access it. You get a blank page or something when you try to access it directly, right? That's because the file is generating a 500 server error. That's not because the file "doesn't exist" (404 error). It's because `$app['database']` is null. I have no idea when or where that variable is defined. Files don't just disappear and get recreated on specific requests.

Comment: appdatabase is in a different directory and is linked to adduser.php, its not null but its showing up as null because the request is made before the file is loaded, I think. I'm trying a different method to solve this now since I can't figure this out. I'm trying to make the add-user.php file send a message to another -php file that can just hold a json object so I can easily access it to display a message. the 500 server error is from my promise ajax request because its file has not loaded. Even without the ajax request I still can't acess add-user.php directly without a form. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: if I don't make the ajax request and don't redirect the file, after I submit the form everything works fine and app database and all the other variables load, nothing is null. So that's why I think its only showing as null because the promise get request is executing before add-user.php is loaded and it only loads on the form submission. Do you know how what I'm trying to do is usually done?  All I can find on here is how to show if a username is taken before the registration form is submitted.

Comment: I'm a noob and I followed a tutorial when I made this, but the file can not exist without me posting to it first. My routes file shows where I can type in a file path to and go to, and what I have to post to go to. Updated my question.

Comment: If your form submits, which I believe it does because you do not stop it from submitting with preventDefault, the page will POST to `action='/users' `, likely interrupting the call to `'/controllers/contact.php'` which is a GET. If you do not feel the need to add a preventDefault, then instead change to `<button type='button' id="myButton">Submit</button>` and change to `document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click'` instead of the register submit. Also check if you should not POST to your controllers